# Jsoup incorrect value children size

Tags: java, html, parsing, dom, jsoup

Jsoup incorrect counts the number of children:

```
    Document document = Jsoup
            .parse(testString);

    Element div = document.select("div").first();
    Elements divChildren = div.children();
    System.out.println(divChildren.size());
```

For example, if testString =

`<div><div><p>text1</p></div><p>text2</p></div>`

or

`<div><h1><p>text1</p></h1><p>text2</p></div>`

then divChildren.size() = **2**

if testString =

```
<div><p><p>text1</p></p><p>text2</p></div>
```

then divChildren.size() = **4**

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at what `document` is holding after parsing

```
String testString ="<div><p><p>text1</p></p><p>text2</p></div>";
```

you will see

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <p></p>
   <p>text1</p>
   <p></p>
   <p>text2</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

As [@Rejesh pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24342491/1393766) `p` can't contain other block-level-elements like `p` itself so Jsoup prevents it by closing such incorrect outer `p` elements (separate closure for opening tag and closing tag). In your case

```
    <p><p>text</p></p>
```

will become

`<p></p><p>text1</p><p></p>`

so your `div`

```
<div><p><p>text1</p></p><p>text2</p></div>
```

will be parsed as

```
  <div>
   <p></p>
   <p>text1</p>
   <p></p>
   <p>text2</p>
  </div>
```

and as you see there are **4** children (two empty `p` and two `p` with text).

---

If you want to turn off this validating mechanism you can use XML parser instead of standard HTML parser with

```
String testString ="<div><p><p>text1</p></p><p>text2</p></div>";

Document document = Jsoup.parse(testString,"",Parser.xmlParser());
System.out.println(document);
Element div = document.select("div").first();
Elements divChildren = div.children();
System.out.println(divChildren.size());
```

will now print **2**.

Answer (score 2):

Because of [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1):

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

Comment: but in real world is often found, as in last case get only direct childrein an amount equal to 2?